# How to efficiently use window.open

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

Please Note: This behavior only appears in Firefox.

If I open a window with `window.open()`, as described in the code below, it might get blocked by the pop up blocker.

```
const openWindow = window.open(...);
```

Firefox then aks the user whether to allow the popup or not and if the user grants the browser the permission to open the window, the window will suddenly open. At this moment however, my variable `openWindow` is already set to `null` and I cannot reference the window anymore.

How can I avoid losing the reference to the window or at least prevent that a window opens after I lost the reference to it?

Comment: There's not much you can do to circumvent a pop up blocker, but you can ask yourself if you really do need a new window or if you can update the current one.

Comment: This code works the same in Chrome and Firefox https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/y7bpp705/ - it does not ask anything

Comment: @mplungjan This will not open a window nor ask to turn off the pop up blocker because it is not triggered by a user event.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't want to circumvent the pop up blocker.

Comment: @michel - have a look at this then https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zod944gx/

Comment: @mplungjan Here you have my case, since I open it using a react action https://jsfiddle.net/zod944gx/1/ You have to hit play, because the onload prevents it automatically.

Comment: In Fx I get "Please allow popups" AND a note in the browser where I can allow. If I allow I do not get any warning anymore. You say you then no longer have access to the popup?

Comment: Does this work better? https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/c4t45hw7/

Comment: The pop up opens after I allow it. The problem is, that I don't have access to the reference `w` that is null.